# Select com médias em minutos - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-select

Abaixo segue uma consulta retornada em uma tabela do meu banco de dados (MySQL):

[image: Consulta retornada do banco de dados]

O que me interessa são as colunas TimeString, VarValue e id. A cada 5 segundos em média é feito um insert no meu sistema. Tenho valores de DateTime de 1 mês.

---

**Dúvida:**

Como que monto consultas que me retornem em intervalos de 1 minuto, 15 minutos, 30 minutos, 1 hora, 1 dia, a média do VarValue? Pode ser consultar separadas, onde o usuário selecionará o intervalo. 
Ou seja, caso ele seleciona-se intervalos a cada 1 hora, deveria ficar da seguinte forma:

TimeString                |     VarValue

2017-10-06 23:50:50       |     30,55

2017-10-06 00:50:55       |     31,55

2017-10-06 01:50:55       |     41,55
...

---

Tentei fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT 
MIN(`i_l1`.`TimeString`) as TimeString, 
AVG(`i_l1`.`VarValue`) as VarValue01

FROM `i_l1`

GROUP BY HOUR( `i_l1`.`TimeString` )
```

Retorno da consulta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que esta consulta não esta gerando de todos os dias, pois tenho dados do dia 06-10 até 16-10, e esta desorganizada a ordem da coluna TimeString.

**Comentário**

Em SQL Server eu havia feito da seguinte forma, porém com outro formato de tabela:

```
SELECT TOP 24 
CAST(CAST(CAST(CAST(table_c1_fatura.E3TimeStamp as float)*24 as bigint) as float)/24 as datetime) as hora,
CAST(CAST(CAST(CAST(table_c1_fatura.E3TimeStamp as float)*24 as bigint) as float)/24 as datetime)+0.04167 as hora_final,
AVG(table_c1_fatura.[PIT970]) AS campo1,
AVG(table_c1_fatura.[FIT964]) AS campo2,
MIN(table_c1_fatura.[TOTALIZADO_FIT964]) as campo3
FROM table_c1_fatura 
WHERE (E3TimeStamp  >= #<%DataInicial%># AND E3TimeStamp <= #<%DataFinal%># AND table_c1_fatura.[TOTALIZADO_FIT964] <> 0 )
GROUP BY CAST(CAST(CAST(CAST(E3TimeStamp as float)*24 as bigint) as float)/24 as datetime)
ORDER BY Hora ASC
```

Poderia ser algo similar ao exemplo a cima.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver utilizando o GROUP BY, segue (**opcaoDesejava**):

```
Intervalos por minuto = ... GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`i_l1`.`TimeString`, '%Y%m%d%H%i')
Intervalos por hora = ... GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`i_l1`.`TimeString`, '%Y%m%d%H')
Intervalos por dia = ... GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`i_l1`.`TimeString`, '%Y%m%d')
```

Sendo que:

```
%d   Dia (00..31)
%e   Dia (0..31)
%m   Mês (00..12)
%y   Ano (dois dígitos)
%Y   Ano (quatro dígitos)
%%   Caractere %
%H   Horas (00..23)
%i   Minutos (00..59)
%s   Segundos (00..59)
%T   Hora completa ( 24 horas, formato hh:mm:ss)
```

Ou seja, o script sql final ficou da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT 
   MIN(`TimeString`) as TimeString, 
   AVG(`VarValue`) as VarValue01
FROM `i_l1`
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`TimeString`, 'opcaoDesejava')
```

Answer (score 0):

encontrei uma forma de fazer um pouco mais simples.

```
SELECT 
--      pc.hora, /* desabilite caso queira conferir */
CASE WHEN 
    (MINUTE(pc.hora)>=0 AND MINUTE(pc.hora) <=29) THEN 
    `0-29`
ELSE
    `30-59` 
END as minutos,
        HOUR(ja.hora) AS horas,
--      MINUTE(ja.hora) AS minutos,
    YEAR(ja.data) AS ano,
    MONTH(ja.data) AS mes,
    DAYOFMONTH(ja.data) AS dia, 
    count(*) AS acessos
 FROM tabela_acesso as ja 
WHERE 
  ja.data >= ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) 

GROUP BY 
horas, ano, mes, dia
ORDER BY dia, mes, ano, horas, minutos ASC;
```